# tint2 ToolbarItem/Button size

Tags: node.js, desktop-application, toolbar

I'm using **[Tint2](https://www.trueinteractions.com/tint2/docs/)** to create a desktop application. I want to use the native toolbar capability, button when I add a `ToolbarItem` ([docs](https://www.trueinteractions.com/tint2/docs/ToolbarItem.html)) to the toolbar, it simply doesn't show up:

[image: Using ToolbarItem]

```
var toolbar = new Toolbar();

var new_button = new ToolbarItem();
    new_button.title = 'Hello';
    new_button.enabled = true;

toolbar.appendChild(new_button);

win.toolbar = toolbar;
```

Similarly, I tried just using a `Button` ([docs](https://www.trueinteractions.com/tint2/docs/Button.html)) instead of a `ToolbarItem` (the latter is recommended in the docs). This results in a very small button - the width property is ignored:

[image: Using Button]

```
var toolbar = new Toolbar();

var new_button = new Button();
    new_button.title = 'Hello';
    new_button.width = '150px';

toolbar.appendChild(new_button);

win.toolbar = toolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you notice on the Toolbar class that there's a property called 'state', it sets what type of display the toolbar uses.  Users can set various preferences as to whether they want to see images, labels or images or labels.

My guess is its default is "image only" and the label isn't used.

```
var toolbar = new Toolbar();

var new_button = new ToolbarItem();
    new_button.title = 'Hello';
    new_button.width = '150px';

toolbar.state = 'label'; // THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT FOR NO IMAGE TOOLBARS.
toolbar.appendChild(new_button);

win.toolbar = toolbar;
```

The second issue you're seeing is the toolbar dictating the width of something. Using your own width may or may not be respected on the toolbar.  You can always just place the button directly within the window and skip the toolbar entirely.

```
var new_button = new Button();
    new_button.title = 'Hello';
    new_button.width = '150px';
    new_button.left = '20px';
    new_button.top = '20px';

win.appendChild(new_button);
```